# Milon barcode packages generates A before and after the barcode number

Tags: php, laravel, barcode

I am using **milon/barcode** package in laravel 8 in order to print the barcodes on the label. It works fine. It prints the barcode correctly on the label. but when I try to scan it using barcode scanner. it gives barcode **A12345678A** but the actual barcode is 12345678

Here is the code.

```
<center class="mb-2"> {!! DNS1D::getBarcodeSVG($barcode->barcode, 'CODABAR', 2, 32, 'black', true) !!}</center>
```

Comment: With codabar, `A` is one of the allowed start/stop characters.  Typically, you program the scanner to discard the start/stop characters when it reads a codabar barcode.

Comment: Do i need to write code to remove that letter from barcode number  ??

Comment: The start/stop characters are part of the barcode.  You need to configure the scanner (barcode reader) to discard them.  Most scanners can be programmed to do so.